# ObjC - Why is instance allowed to access class extension property in .m file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, class-extensions

As is known that in ObjC property declared in .h file is the interface "visible outside", while property declared in .m file (class extension) can be only accessed in .m, kind of "private" or "hidden". But in practice code as follows can be compiled.

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
+ (void)foo;
@end
```

ClassA.m

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@interface ClassA ()
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger aInt;
@end

@implementation ClassA 
+ (void)foo {
    ClassA *aObj = [ClassA new];
    aObj.aInt = 2;  //?
}
@end

@interface _ClassB : NSObject  //Some private class defined in the same .m file...
@end
@implementation _ClassB

+ (void)bar {
    ClassA* aObj = [ClassA new];
    aObj.aInt = 2;  //?
}

@end
```

The fact is, not only `ClassA *aObj` defined in `ClassA`'s own method can access class extension property `aInt`, but `ClassA *aObj` defined in another `_ClassB` while in the same ClassA.m file can also access `aInt`.

As far as I understand, `aObj` defined in class method `foo` has no difference with any `ClassA *` type variable defined in another class and separate .m file. But by no means will the latter access 'aInt', say

ClassC.m

```
#import "ClassA.h"
...
- (void)fun {
   ClassA *aObj = [ClassA new];
   NSLog("%d", aObj.aInt);  //Error! Property aInt not found on object of type 'ClassA*'
}
```

Why is this happening? Can this be explained with ObjC runtime mechanism or something?

Comment: Because `objective-c` language doesn't have private methods and properties. You can **simulate** accessibility only in compile time by hiding their declaration, but anyway in runtime they will be public. For example you can call private api and apple can forbid it only by rejecting distribution in appstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the Objective C runtime. In fact, if you use key value coding, you can access *any* property and/or method from *any* class from *any* source file you want, may it be declared private or not, or in an extension or directly. This is how some people (forbiddenly) use private APIs of Apple.

Objective C, like C, just needs to *know* the declarations of your class. This is done by importing the header files. The header file says "Look, there is something like `ClassA`, it has these methods and those properties", and then you can use them.

Anything that is declared in a .m file is not visible to other source files, because you typically do not import .m files (although, technically, it works). Nevertheless, the declaration still *exist* - just the compiler does not know of it when compiling the other file.

You could create a dummy header file:

```
// FakeClassAExtension.h
// ...
@interface ClassA (Fake)
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger aInt;
@end
```

and then use it in your `ClassC`:

```
// ClassC.m
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "FakeClassAExtension.h"
//...
- (void)fun {
    ClassA *aObj = [ClassA new];
    NSLog("%d", aObj.aInt);  //Fine
}
```

When compiling `ClassC.m`, the compiler get's to know that someting like `aInt` exists in `ClassA`. The linker - as the final step - then checks if this really is true, e.g. if one (and only one) of the compiled source files contained the definition of `aInt`.

Try this: Just *declare* a property that is not *defined* anywhere:

```
// FakeClassAExtension2.h
// ...
@interface ClassA (Fake2)
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger oopsDoesItExist;
@end
```

and then use it:

```
// ClassC.m
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "FakeClassAExtension2.h"
//...
- (void)fun {
    ClassA *aObj = [ClassA new];
    NSLog("%d", aObj.oopsDoesItExist);  //Compiler is fine here
}
```

The compiler will compile the code, but the linker then will say that there is no *definition* of `oopsDoesItExist`

Just a final remark: You can define *iVars* or synthesize properties only in class extensions (anonymous categories) within an .m file. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed and clear answer!